# Export CPU usage of SINGLE PROCESS in csv format

Tags: monitoring

I want to collect data about the CPU utilization of a SINGLE PROCESS over time. 
I tried to wrap the collection of data (e.g. using pidstat) in a while loop
with a one second sleep, but it does not work. I also tried using collectl but I did not manage to find an option to collect the data of a single process (I tried with --procfilter p , but the output was not reliable.

Is there a standard (possible open source) tool that measures the CPU utilization of a SINGLE PROCESS (using the PID) over time and gives the possibility to dump these data in a csv file?

Answer (score 0):

This one does the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
pidstat | grep 1117 >>pidload.csv
sleep 1
done
```

Just put it in a shell script. 1117 in this case is the process id you want to track. chmod +x SCRIPTNAME and you are good to go.

if you want specific data, you can awk it, like so:

```
pidstat | grep 1117 | awk '{ print $3, $8 }' >>pidload.csv
```

Comment: Maybe I described my problem wrongly. But I came up with a very similar thing but sometimes my server did not write the result in the csv file.

BTW you can use `pidstat -p <pid>` to get directly the stats of a single pid.

Comment: Yes, you can use pidstat -p <pid>. But look at all the garbage you will also write to the file. Also try to awk the result this way? This one is tried and tested. I don't actively use it. I just wrote it for you. But for me it works. It records the data in the csv file every second. It does what you asked for.

Comment: Yes and no. I very appreciate your answer, because it may be helpful for others too, but I asked: `Is there a **standard** (possible open source) tool that measures the CPU utilization of a SINGLE PROCESS (using the PID) over time and gives the possibility to dump these data in a csv file?`.

Comment: True. I did notice the question. I have to admit, I don't know an according tool by heart. But as I said, the script does the job and given your text, it would be a valid solution, since you stated, that you tried something similar yourself. And yes, I do hope it does help others too. A fast one on Google gave me the following, which might be worth taking a look at:
CPU-MEM-monitor: https://github.com/f18m/CPU-MEM-monitor
dstat: https://www.tecmint.com/dstat-monitor-linux-server-performance-process-memory-network/
atop: https://haydenjames.io/use-atop-linux-server-performance-analysis/